# How to fix 'Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable' error in Xcode

Tags: swift

I create a random number and assign it to the variable `randomNumber`. Then when I try to append the random number as an index for the `emojis` array to the empty array `arrayOfEmojis` I get the error:

> 'Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable'

Im also getting errors from the emoji?

```
import GameKit

struct EmojiProvider {
    var emojis = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "☺️", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
    var arrayOfEmojis: [String]

    func generateEmoji() -> [String] {
        for i in 1...3 {
            var randomNumber = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt(upperBound: emojis.count)
            arrayOfEmojis.append(emojis[randomNumber]) //error!
        }
        return arrayOfEmojis
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because when you have a `struct`, instead of a `class`, you're mutating the instance itself.
Hence, when you're trying to mutate `self`, mark the function as `mutating`:

```
mutating func generateEmoji() -> [String] {
```

Also, I suggest you select a random element as follows:

```
return (1...3).compactMap { _ in emojis.randomElement() }
```

...and leave our the whole `arrayOfEmojis`, if you don't want to access it later.

---

The full code would then be:

```
struct EmojiProvider {
    var emojis = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "☺️", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]

    mutating func generateEmoji() -> [String] {
        return (1...3).compactMap { _ in emojis.randomElement() }
    }
}
```

---

What you could also do, is make `EmojiProvider` a class, instead of a struct.
You could then have the following code:

```
class EmojiProvider {
    var emojis = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "☺️", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]

    func generateEmoji() -> [String] {
        return (1...3).compactMap { _ in emojis.randomElement() }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that a `struct` is a value type and when you modify any of its instance properties, you actually modify the struct instance itself. Hence, when you call `append` on `arrayOfEmojis`, you not only mutate `arrayOfEmojis`, but you mutate the `EmojiProvider` instance itself as well. You can get rid of the warning by marking your function as mutating.

```
mutating func generateEmoji() -> [String] { ...
```

However, it seems to me that what you are actually trying to do is simply getting 3 random elements from the array, while what your current implementation is doing is fetching 3 random elements from the array every time the `generateEmoji` function is called and appending those to the `arrayOfEmojis` array, which just keeps getting bigger and bigger as you keep calling the `generateEmoji` function.

To get that behaviour, change your implementation to the following:

```
struct EmojiProvider {
    var emojis = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "☺️", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]

    func generateEmoji() -> [String] {
        var arrayOfEmojis = [String]()
        for _ in 1...3 {
            let randomNumber = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt(upperBound: emojis.count)
            arrayOfEmojis.append(emojis[randomNumber])
        }
        return arrayOfEmojis
    }
}
```

Or an even simpler implementation of `generateEmoji` using `map`:

```
func generateEmoji() -> [String] {
    return (1...3).map{_ ->String in emojis[GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt(upperBound: emojis.count)]}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Mutable array, you can access and delete like this

```
var languages: NSMutableArray = ["Swift", "C", "Objective-C"]
var randomInt = Int.random(in: 0...length)
if let text_let = languages[randomInt] as? String
{
    text = text_let
}
languages.removeObject(at: randomInt)
```